# Calling Qt C++ code from ORACLE via Extproc

Tags: c++, oracle, qt

Not much info on the subject and a lot of problems for those trying to delve there, since ppl attempting this are usually incompetent either in oracle or in c++ (I am a total oracle noob for example).

The borderline between the two is a truly dark and frustrating region. This post is intended to make it less frustrating, or at least, less dark.

I will not discuss actual linking to c++ code here, as this is explained in most manuals. Instead I want to discuss some **things, most likely to cause trouble**.

See below:

**dll caching**

**static variables**

**default path**

**event loops**

Please note that I am only sharing my experience, not proposing solutions as what I do is more than likely to be objectionable. So, I welcome discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that my working config is Centos 5.5 + Oracle XE + Qt4.7

**important**

QxtLogger (or things like it) is your best friend. You won't be able to debug calls via extproc so log, **a lot**. Or it will be hell. (It will be hell any way tbh, but at least  you won't be fried AND blinded at the same time). note Q **xt**, this is nifty not so little library extending Qt with some really useful stuff.

**Dll caching**

Ok, it is said that when extproc is called a cached version of DLL is compared to the one on hard drive and newer one is loaded. I have found that this is **NOT** always the case.
More than once I've seen my parser calls to be done to older version of library than present on HDD. It fixes itself, just not immediately. Keep in mind.

**Suggestion:** always logging library version into a file to be sure of what's really happening.

**static variables**

It is quite easy to overlook what oracle has to say on the point (especially if you are as inexperienced with oracle as I am, so almost **all** docs make little to no sense). This is important though. Although static function variables **may** work due to the aforementioned dll caching, they are **not guaranteed** to work.

For example, this was the first thing we tested at work:

"make library, make func with static variable, make 2 consequent calls, see that it is kept, happily go with DLL approach"

**this was wrong :(**

just recently I noticed that these "kept variables" are no longer kept... and each call spends approx 1 second "pre-loading" dictionaries from DB... lol.

**Suggestion:**  extproc calls should somehow invoke a process that already exists on the server. For example in my case - I separated parser library into an executable that  is always running on the server and a library that exchanges data with this process via QxtRPCPeer (tool to trasfer signal/slots calls between Qt applications)

**default path:**

Yup. Try calling qxtLog->debug(QDir::currentPath()); from extproc invoked Dll. This is seriously not funny and can cost you any amount of frustration. If you want to use anything path dependand in extproc invoked library  **make sure to set the path yourself**.

Chances are : this problem will also cause QOCI driver not load automatically from sqldrivers folder. Use this code instead :

```
QPluginLoader loader("sqldrivers\\qsqlocid4.dll");
qxtLog->trace(loader.fileName());
QObject *plugin = loader.instance();
qxtLog->trace(loader.errorString());
if (!plugin)
    return;

QSqlDriverPlugin *sqlPlugin  = qobject_cast<QSqlDriverPlugin *>(plugin);

if (!sqlPlugin )
    qxtLog->critical("Failed to load plugin");
else
    qxtLog->trace("Successfull plugin load");

QSqlDriver * driver = sqlPlugin->create("QOCI");
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(driver, "Connection name");
```

Logging is there so that you can always check why is the application failing;

Please note that you can only use things like "sqldrivers\qsqlocid4.dll" after the QDir::currentPath has been set to point somewhere.

**event loops:**

Obviously - no event loop for such libraries. QCoreApplication::instance() returns NULL too ,btw . Meaning - no signal/slot calls. Do not even try. Tbh, I really want someone to show me how to properly use signals in such scenario.
For my task, I settled with calling QProcess (that actually does all the work), then using godsend function QProcess::waitForFinished() that **works without event loop**

So, these are my observations. Feel free to correct me. I would be happy to learn of proper ways.